# Vim LaTeX Suite is too slow to open a big file

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, latex-suite

I am having problems with [vim LaTeX Suite](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/) opening big files like [this](http://www.diaz-caro.info/test.tex) (which is not that big, just 195K).

The opening of this file takes up to about 8 seconds. If I comment all the lines, it opens instantaneously, so I guess LaTeX Suite is somehow parsing the file. It also opens fast if I remove the file extension, so it is definitely a LaTeX Suite problem.

I really like using vim and I hope there is some way to fix this. I have other files, a bit longer, which takes up to one minute to open.

I am using an up-to-date Arch Linux. Vim version is 7.4 (Arch package 7.4.16-2) and LaTeX Suite is from Arch package vim-latexsuite 20130126-1

I have already reported the problem in the [vim LaTeX Suite mailing list](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=contact&title=Contact) (back in July), but I didn't get any answer yet.

Comment: Have you considered using vim without latex-suite? It isn't too hard to add a bunch of lines to your ftplugin/latex.vim file that reproduce some of the more lightweight latex-suite functions, while avoiding some of the "bloat" of latex-suite.

Comment: No, I didn't try. I use a lot of functionalities of latex-suite, but I guess I could survive without most of them.
Anyway, I want also to get confirmation that this is actually a bug and not just some issue with my configuration.

Comment: I can confirm that your test file opens instantly in (g)vim without latex-suite, so the problem lies (probably) with latex-suite and not the basic functionality that vim provides for .tex files (like syntax highlighting etc.).

Comment: I also found that the snipmate plugin adds a lot of the functionality I used to use latex-suite for (mostly shortcuts to define complex environments etc.).

Comment: Thanks. I am moving to LaTeX-Box, which is way simpler, but enough.

Comment: Use a Vim that has profiling built-in (e.g. the version that ships with Cygwin), and find out what exactly is causing the slowdown.

Comment: Thanks! I just did it, and the problem is in tex_latexSuite.vim:
54786.039  54715.189  54545.964: sourcing /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftplugin/tex_latexSuite.vim
(i.e. ~55 sec)

Comment: I went back to LaTeX Suite, it is way better than the alternatives, even it it takes 1 minute to open a 3000+ lines file (and even when their developers do not answer the bug reports)